# To find a substring in a given string

Tags: c++

This is my program to find whether a substring exists in a Person's name or not. The implementation of the search function seems correct to me but still, it's not working when I run it in code blocks. There are no compilation errors but it doesn't work properly at runtime.

---

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 using namespace std;
class Person
{
    char *name;
public:
    Person(char* n)
    {
       name=n;
    }
    bool search(char* substr)
    {
        char *str=name;
        while(*str!='\0')
        {   int count=0;
            if(*str==*substr)
            {   char *s=substr;
                char *p=str;

                while(*s!='\0')
                {
                  if(*p==*s)
                     {
                          count++;
                          p++;
                          s++;
                     }
                  else
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(count==strlen(substr))
            {
                cout<<name<<endl;
                return true;
            }
            str++;
        }
        return false;
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout<<name<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Person p("Akhil");
    char *s;
    cout<<"Enter substring to be found:"<<endl;
    gets(s);
    if(p.search(s))
        cout<<"Found!!!\n";
    else
        cout<<"Not Found!!!\n";
}
```

---

It will be very helpful if someone can tell me where I am making mistake in the implementation of the search function. I can't use a standard library function to implement it as it's mentioned in my assignment.

Comment: Why not to use `if (s1.find(s2) != std::string::npos) {
    std::cout << "found!" << '\n';
}`?

Comment: In my assignment, it's mentioned to implement a search function by myself without using any standard library functions.

Comment: Asking homework questions is fine, but then you have to mention that you are required to implement that yourself instead of using a library function.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie here. I will take care of that from next time.

Comment: You can also edit your question to add it now ;)
Unrelated, but you should take a look at [Why is using namespace std considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work properly at runtime"? Can you give us an example input and describe what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess: The problem is how you read the string. `gets()` is deprecated since c++11 and removed as of c++14 [as you can read here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets). You should use `std::cin` (since you are allow to use `std::cout` for ouput this should also be allowed?):

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
if(p.search(s.c_str()))
...
```

Problem could be, that `gets` will read input from the console and place it in the buffer you provide. But since you don't initialize your buffer `s`, you get undefined behaviour.

In addition you should replace `char *` with `const char*`, since you are not going to modify any of the strings.

Also avoid `using namespace std`.

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes in the code worked on my end.
Have used const char *name; as in Person p("Akhil"); is invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

class Person
{
    const char *name;
public:
    Person(const char* n)
    {
       name=n;
    }
    bool search(char* substr)
    {
        const char *str=name;
        while(*str!='\0')
        {   int count=0;

            if(*str==*substr)
            {   char *s=substr;
                const char *p=str;
                while(*s!='\0')
                {
                  if(*p==*s)
                     {
                          count++;
                          p++;
                          s++;
                     }
                  else
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(count==strlen(substr))
            {
                cout<<name<<endl;
                return true;
            }
            str++;
        }
        return false;
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout<<name<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Person p("Akhil");
    char* s;
    cout<<"Enter substring to be found:"<<endl;
    gets(s);
    if(p.search(s))
        cout<<"Found!!!\n";
    else
        cout<<"Not Found!!!\n";
}
```

output i got:

```
Enter substring to be found:
kh
Akhil
Found!!!

--------------------------------
Process exited with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Software used: Dev-C++ 5.4.2

Compiler used: Compiler: TDM-GCC 4.7.1 64-bit Release

Comment: You removed `using namespace std`, but still write `cout` instead of `std::cout`, so it does not even compile.
Also you are using the outdated `gets` with an *uninitilized* buffer `s` -> undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add another condition to the inside while loop.

```
while(*s != '\0' && *p != '\0')
{
    if(*p == *s)
    {
        count++;
        p++;
        s++;
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

The reason being you can reach the end of `p` before reaching the end of `s`. For example if the string is `Akhil` and the substring to be found is `ill`.

Comment: No, but in that case, the loop will break automatically when *p!=*s.

Comment: Ah right, it works with C-style strings but won't work with iterators of class string.